# Mysterious windows emoji keyboard textbox?

Tags: windows-10, emoji-keyboard

Sometime ago, I stumbled upon this weird feature where when I open the windows emoji keyboard when certain things are in focus (the task bar or desktop icons), text input is directed into this mysterious textbox in the upper left hand corner of the screen.
Interestingly the font of the inputted text changes based on what is in focus.

Does anyone have any ideas about the reasons or origins behind this?

[image: Mysterious textbox]

Comment: It's the literally called, the emoji panel, and it was added to Windows with the release of `Windows 10 version 1903`.  If you are talking about the search field, it's a search field, used to search for emoji by name.

Comment: my question is referring to the white textbox in the upper left hand corner, it doesn't always appear when you have focus on something that doesn't accept text input

Comment: It appears to be the search functionality, based on the message indicating, there are no emojis that match your search.

Comment: well yeah, I do understand that when you open the emoji panel, you can search through the emoji by just typing right there and then. And if you have focus on a text field, your search term is entered into that field. And then when you select an emoji, that search term is replace with that chosen emoji, etc.

What I don't understand and find curious is that when you open the emoji panel when no text field is in focus and you just start typing, or just selecting emoji, why should a mysterious textbox materialize in the corner of the screen and capture this output.